# Exception while opening epub file in C#

Tags: c#, epub

I am trying to read epub book using C#.NET but I am getting the following excetion:
Object reference not set to instance of an object.

I am trying epub for the first time and [this](http://epubreader.codeplex.com/) is where I have referred.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Epub book = new Epub(@"d:\test.epub"); //this is the line where i am getting error
                String Title = book.Title[0];
                String Author = book.Creator[0];

                Console.WriteLine("Name:" + Title);
                Console.WriteLine("Author:" + Author);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Comment: The `test.epub` file could be corrupted or have unexpected(from lib point of view) format. Does this happen for all the `epub` files you have?

Comment: @GrantWinney I tried single step debugging and the exception was on the same line. Tried moving the file to desktop, my documents but no change.

Comment: @Downvoter: I have gone through that answer before posting here but it talks about how object can be null and how to check if it is not null before accessing it.

Comment: @aleksey.berezan Thanks, that helped. Tried many ways but not the one you suggested. It is working fine now.:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to run your code locally and it worked on my machine. And it works for other `epub` files, as you've said in comment.
Also I've taken a brief look into [Epub](https://epubreader.codeplex.com/)'s code-base and didn't find anything that could obviously cause the error, plus `NullReferenceException` means that:

1. Your `epub` file is broken or corrupted
2. Your `epub` file does not have some specific piece of (meta)data that `Epub` lib expects.

In both cases I'd recommend you to try to re-create/re-convert that not working `d:\test.epub` file or abandon it :)